# How do I know which cell is highlighted in jexcell javascript library?

Tags: javascript, jexcelapi, jexceljs

I want to merge the cells marked with jexcel. I don't know how to do that. More specifically, I want to merge cells into a dynamic state and write them into merged cells in MySQL. How to do it

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script>

var data = [
  ['', 'Ford', 'Tesla', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
  ['2017', 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ['2018', 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ['2019', 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = document.getElementById('example');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  filters: true,
  dropdownMenu: true,
  contextMenu: true
});

</script>
```

Comment: have you tried these? `$('#spreasheet').jexcel('getSelection');
$('#spreasheet').jexcel('getCellCursor');
$('#spreasheet').jexcel('getSelectedCells');`

Comment: I edited the question. Take a look. Here's how to identify the location marked with the mouse on this code? I am a PHP backend programmer. I can't do much in JavaScript

Comment: I'm confused, are you using Handsontable or jExcel?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Question is not clear but I'll try to answer it to the best of my ability.

if I ignore the example you provided and focus on jExcel, we can merge cells using `setMerge` and for that we need to know:

- the address of the first cell
- the numbers of selected rows
- numbers of selected columns

we can extract this info from:

```
$("#spreadsheet").jexcel("getSelectedRows", true);
$("#spreadsheet").jexcel("getSelectedColumns", true);
```

in theory this alone should work, but jExcel deselects cells when it loses focus (ie when user clicks a button) that's why I used a workarround to store the selection of cells in an object, and later used that object to merge cells.

## HTML:

```
<div id="spreadsheet"></div>
<br>
<input id="myB" type="button" value="Merge Selected" />
```

## Javascript:

```
var mySlection = {};
var options = {
  minDimensions: [10, 10],
  onselection: storeSelection
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var mySpreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").jexcel(options);


  $("#myB").click(function() {
    //Merge Cells using the stored selection
    $("#spreadsheet").jexcel("setMerge", mySlection.firstcell, mySlection.colspan, mySlection.rowspan)
    /*
    you may now store the following values to your MySQL
    mySlection.firstcell
    mySlection.colspan
    mySlection.rowspan
    */
  });
});


function storeSelection() {
  var sRows = $("#spreadsheet").jexcel("getSelectedRows", true);
  var sCols = $("#spreadsheet").jexcel("getSelectedColumns", true);

  mySlection.firstcell = [sCols[0], sRows[0]];
  mySlection.colspan = sCols.length;
  mySlection.rowspan = sRows.length;
}
```

**Requirements:** jQuery, jExcel and jSuites v3

## [Here's a Working Example at CodePen](https://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/ExVBrQQ)

Comment: Thank you, i will check